# R: How many variables are needed for a good multiple regression model?

Tags: r, regression, self-study

I'm still very new to statistics and R and I hope you're not going to downvote me. Before asking this question, I searched for answers, but couldn't find an exact guide on how to proceed here. This one is probably very simple for people with more experience on the topic.

I have a data set "houses.csv" with a lot of real estate data, which contains of the following variables:

- price
- bathrooms
- sqft_living
- sqft_lot
- floors
- waterfront:(0: no, 1: yes)
- view: number or visits so far (0 to 4)
- condition: (1 to 5)
- grade: (from 1 to 13)
- sqft_above
- sqft_basement
- yr_built
- yr_renovated: (renovation year, "0" if not
  renovated at all)
- zipcode
- lat: Latitude
- long: Longitude

My task is to create a MLR (multiple linear regression) model in R, which explains the **price**.

I am confused, because I am not sure if I should use every variable in order to create this model or just pick a few of them?

What I have done so far, trying to create this model with all the variables is:

```
price_house.lm <- 
lm(price ~ bedrooms + bathrooms + sqft_living + sqft_lot + floors + waterfront + view + condition + grade + sqft_above + sqft_basement + yr_built + yr_renovated + zipcode + lat + long, data = houses)
```

The output is:

[image]

Is this correct or should I use less variables in order to explain the relationship to "price" ?

Comment: Your question is hard to address directly, as it depends heavily on context and relates to more than one topic in statistics. If this is homework, you should state so in your question with the 'self-study' tag. If it is not homework, you should further clarify what your goal here is. You say you want to 'explain price', and you should be aware this is a different goal than 'predicting price'. You can check 'The Two Cultures' by Breiman (2001) or 'To explain or to predict' by Shmueli (2010), for more info. Depending on your goal, you are interested in what is called 'variable selection'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, this is a homework. I added the "self-study" tag. The exact formulation of the homework is "to explain price". The "to predict" task comes after this one. If I can provide more specific information, which would support helping me with the solution, I'd gladly do it. Thanks for the sources: I will read them and try to find a solution by myself as well.

Comment: Is the “sqft_basement” variable equal to “sqft_living” minus “sqft_above”?

Comment: The way you have modeled this, you treat `zipcode` as a numerical value that is assumed to have a linear association with `price`. Does that really make sense?

Comment: @Dave Yes, thank you mentioning this. I didn't really noticed this until I read your comment.

Comment: @EdM yes, you are right. This doesn't make sense. I kept it in the "equation", because I wanted to explore if there could be a relationship between zipcode (= approximate location) and price.

Comment: Latitude and longitude do not tend to act linearly on the response. The question should rather be: "how do I well represent features in a hedonic model" than "how many features should I use". Tip: Always think hard about the problem at hand before blindly fitting models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title question "How many variables are needed for a good multiple regression model?" doesn't have a general answer. In principle good models can be found with any number of variables, and for sure any model becomes worse if variables that are in fact important are removed.

A major problem with a large number of variables is that estimation of many coefficients becomes very unstable or even impossible if the number of observations is small. A (rather crude) rule of thumb has it that the number of observations should be at least ten times the number of variables. This seems to be the case here, it looks like you have more than 450 observations, which should normally be fine for 15 variables.

Other reasons to remove variables are the following: You may, in the future, want to make predictions based on fewer variables, because some variables are costly to measure or hard to find for other reasons. In this case variable selection should depend on information of this kind.

Some variables may be strongly correlated with each other, which means that they share certain information which isn't attributed to either of these variables individually by the tests in the output. This can lead to numerical problems (not sure what explains the `NA` for `sqft_basement` - this should for sure be explained with potential consequences), and can also lead to potentially misleading interpretation of insignificant t-tests. The latter problem is however not really solved by removing variables, because if two variables share the same information, removing one of them is still often misinterpreted stating that only the remaining variables have an influence and the others don't, which isn't appropriate in such a case.

Furthermore, in case that some variables are really uninformative "noise", it may be possible to find a model with better prediction performance that has fewer variables. This may also hold in case of many variables sharing the same information, see above. Prediction performance can be assessed by techniques such as cross-validation.

Some people also state that variables should be removed in order to have a model that is easier to interpret, but I think this is in most cases mistaken, because significant variables are rarely removed, and therefore one can also interpret the full model in a simplifying manner concentrating on the significant variables, which is more appropriate because this model takes into account more information than a model with fewer variables (but see the remark about correlation above).

You see that to some extent whether variables should be removed depends on how the model is later used and interpreted.

Now one further major thing to keep in mind is that variable selection has problematic implications. It will normally bias estimators and invalidate the tests and further inference obtained from the standard Least Squares fit. For this reason I will always ask first whether there is a strong reason to remove variables in the given situation (one of those above), and otherwise I'd recommend to stick to the full model. Very often (at least with enough observations) this is better than any selection.

Obviously I'm assuming here that there is no issue with other model assumptions such as linearity, absence of outliers, independence etc., which should be checked in any case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the profound and insightful answer! I read it several times. It really helped me to decide, based on the data and the goal, which variables to use. In the end, I used all of them and I learned a lot about regression analysis while building the final model.